# Email Validation using two files doesn't work in Android app

Tags: java, android

I prepared XML file with EditText and Button. 
I have two java files when I should check my email. I do everything as You wrote in the other questions.... but something is wrong.... I don't know what...

The first file MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);
        EditText emailInput= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    {
                        String input = emailInput.getText().toString();
                        if (isValidEmail(input)) {
                            Correct();
                        } else {
                            Incorrect();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public void Correct(){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Your e-mail is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void Incorrect(){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Your e-mail is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }
```

and the second file, where I used regex:

```
    public class EmailValidator {

        public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}");

            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(target);
            return m.matches();

        }
    }
```

What is wrong? Where is a mistake?

Comment: I have the same to you : "what is wrong" ? What are your inputs ? expected outputs ? obtained outputs ?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider being more specific about the problems. If it's a crash, have a look at the logcat for exception stacktrace.

Anyway, some obvious ones:

```
if (isValidEmail(input))
```

This needs to be scoped as

```
if (EmailValidator.isValidEmail(input))
```

unless you have a static import for that function. This would be a compile-time error.

Then these `findViewById()` calls:

```
Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);
EditText emailInput= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
```

need to be after `setContentView()`. Before `onCreate()` there's a `NullPointerException` because the activity window is not yet set up, and before `setContentView()` nulls will be returned as such views don't exist, resulting in a `NullPointerException` later. These would be runtime errors.